# why my flask app is not posting the posts in formpage.html?

Tags: python, html, flask, jinja2

**i am learning flask library for building web applications.when i implemented that i got bugs.i have solved problem of my own but not work it just shows form not posting my blog.please help me to solve this matter.I will be thankfull.**
*i have one python file and two html files*
*and one forms.db file.*

**application.py**

````
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'sqlite:///forms.db'
db = SQLAlchemy(app)
class blog(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    title = db.Column(db.String(100) , nullable=False)
    content = db.Column(db.Text , nullable=False)
    author = db.Column(db.String(20) , nullable=False)
    def __repr__(self):
        return 'blog post ' + str(self.id)
@app.route("/", methods=['GET','POST'])
def formation():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        show_title = request.form.get('title')
        show_content = request.form.get('content')
        show_author = request.form.get('author')
        new_blog = blog(title=show_title, content=show_content, author=show_author)
        db.session.add(new_blog)
        db.session.commit()
        return redirect('/')
    else:    
        allP = blog.query.all()        
        return render_template('formpage.html',posts=allP)
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)```
````

**formpage.html**

[image: this is my formpage.html image.i think code is not working due to this html file..]

**base.html**
[image: this is base.html file i just extends this to formpage.html..]

Comment: it helps us to have your code inline

Answer (score 0):

You need a `submit` type input:

```html
<input type="submit" value="post"/>
```

instead of `type="button"`